# How jersey is returning json response automatically if we have not calling getter methods.of pojo class

Tags: java, jersey-2.0

I am learning restful service. This is my first program. I am setting values to pojo class through setter methods. How jersey is returning response in json format as i am not calling pojo class getter methods. Question is specifically about how jersey is using getter methods.

```java
      public class Customer {

        private int custNo;
        private String custName;
        private String custCountry;

        public int getCustNo() {
            return custNo;
        }
        public void setCustNo(int custNo) {
            this.custNo = custNo;
        }
        public String getCustName() {
            return custName;
        }
        public void setCustName(String custName) {
            this.custName = custName;
        }
        public String getCustCountry() {
            return custCountry;
        }
        public void setCustCountry(String custCountry) {
            this.custCountry = custCountry;
        }    
        }

        {
        "custCountry": "India",
        "custName": "Java4s",
        "custNo": 1
        }
```

Comment: Jersey is probably calling the getters

Comment: Matching getters are called on serialization and matching setters are called for Deserialization. Javabean naming convention is used to determine the matching of JSON properties and POJO properties.